# Amazon AWS: Preemptive is mistakenly pausing my (ec2) service, how to prevent this?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance doing a long running job. The job should take about a week but after a week it is only at 31%. I believe this is due to the low average cpu (less than 1%) and because it very rarely receives a GET request (just me checking the status).

Reason for low cpu:
this Java service performs many GET requests then processes a batch of pages once it has a few hundred (non-arbitrary, there is a reason they are all required first). but to prevent me getting http 429 (too many requests) i must time my GET requests apart using `Thread.sleep(x)` and synchronization. this results in a very low cpu which spikes every so often.

I think amazons preemptive systems think that my service is arbitrarily waiting, when in actual fact it needs to wake up at a specific moment. I also notice that if i check the status more often then it goes quicker.

How do i stop amazons preemptive system thinking my service isn't doing anything?

I have thought of 2 solutions, however neither seems intuitive:

1. have another process running to keep the cpu at ~25%. which would only really consist of

```
while(true){
  Thread.sleep(300);
  LocalDateTime until = LocalDateTime.now().plusMillis(100);
  while(LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(until){
    //empty loop
  }
}
```

however this just seems like an unnecessary use of resources.

2. have a process on my laptop perform a GET request to the aws service every 10 minutes. but one of the reasons i put it on aws was to free up my laptop, although this would be magnitudes less resources of my laptop than having the service run locally.

Is one of these solutions more desirable than the other? Is there another solution which would be more appropriate?

Many Thanks,

edit: note, I use the free-tier services only.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "preemptive system" on Amazon EC2. However, if you are using a burstable instance (eg from the T2 or T3 family), then there are limits to the _maximum_ CPU over sustained periods. See: [Burstable performance instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html) You certainly do _not_ want to be consuming CPU for no purpose, since it will limit your ability to burst.

Comment: yes, it is the t2.micro. I will read that link now, thanks.

Comment: i very much doubt it is hitting the cpu limit as even when it spikes it is only 10% or so and thats at least 20mins apart. however this does show the boosting the cpu will not effectively solve the slow completion time. can you please help me with the upper limits for the t2.micro

Comment: Aside from CPU 'burst' limitations, micro instances have limited network bandwidth. So, if you are downloading a lot of content, this could also be a bottleneck. I encourage you to try an a different instance family (even if only for a day or so) to compare the difference. `a1.medium` is only 60c/day and `m6g.medium` is 92c/sday.

Comment: i think that is the problem. scrolling through the logs I found 322 consecutive HttpClient errors - since it waits 16 seconds on that error this has a time span of just under 1.5 hours - which should never realistically happen for this specific error. unfortunately i do not intend on launching a paid for service. i will do the long running job locally then host the service after it has finished.

Comment: sad to see this limit is so low, not even big documents, just standard html pages. i will try this on google cloud console, maybe their free (or low tier after trial ends) will have realistic limits.

Comment: The AWS instance type is _not_ causing your HTTP errors. Nor is it causing a 16 second delay. You would be much better off doing some debugging rather than blaming the external environment.

Comment: FYI, some web sites block access from the IP address ranges of Amazon EC2 instances specifically to prevent 'scraping'. This _might_ be the cause of your HttpClient errors. I highly recommend that you do not violate the terms of a website. If they want you to access the data, they will provide an API.